# Providing both a current and single historical snapshot of an H2 database

Tags: hibernate, jpa, h2

I'm currently working on a java application backed by an H2 database which will periodically generate various files based on its model (how frequent will be configurable and currently defaults to once an hour). To support this batched behaviour, I need to provide two versions of the data-model on user request - the "Current" version which can be edited freely, and the "Enforced" version which is read-only and can be used to query the actual behaviour of the system. The solutions I've come up with are:

- I could add historical data to the database and derive the enforced version from that. We're wary of this option as the model is quite complex with a lot of many-to-many relationships and we don't want to make things worse (I'm not even sure how I could maintain an easily queryable history of join tables via Hibernate)
- I could copy the database to a second location and provide access to both. This was the first solution someone suggested to me, but I don't like the idea of constantly having to close all connections to both whilst waiting for the copy to take place.
- I could maintain the two databases side-by-side, and provide my own implementation of EntityManager for writes which wraps an entity manager for each database, commits the transaction to the current version, and flushes to the enforced version but does not commit so that other EntityManagers will not see the changes. I started implementing this but it feels fragile, and if the application restarts without doing the commit (which is likely; making shutdowns contingent on completing a file write will not always be possible) then it'll be back to doing a full copy for the first write.
- I could maintain two databases and persist a list of all the transaction objects that come in. Then on a file write the stored transactions can be applied to the enforced model and cleared out. This is what I'm currently leaning towards, it should be reliable as the transactions are persistently queued and written to be idempotent and atomic, so it will be resilient to crashes etc. Still it feels like there should be a more elegant way.

Is there anything better for providing a sort of actively available historical snapshot like this in a simple and reasonably performant way?

Comment: You could use the [online backup](http://h2database.com/html/grammar.html#backup). You don't need to close any connection for that. Online backup is fast, as it's low level (basically copying the file). Would that be an option?

Comment: That may well work, I'll try it out and see how it behaves, thanks for the suggestion!